# W2k8 RC1: Windows Media Servers (WMS) as proxy

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy, streaming, windows

(fullquote from stackoverflow.com/questions/2690788/w2k8-rc1-windows-media-servers-wms-as-proxy/2690791#2690791)

I will have one streaming-server (W2k8, unknown streaming protocol [rtsp, mss, http]) and half dozen streaming-servers as proxies to save bandwidth.

I have read the documentation and installed the modules, but I am unsure how I have to configure the proxy's according to http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee126142(en-us,WS.10).aspx - as a proxy or reverse proxy and how I minimize the bandwidth needs between origin server and proxy's.

What is the best way to realize my setup? Any short how-tos? How can I announce all players to use the proxy? Route all rtsp/mms/http-requests through my proxy? Announce the proxy with DHCP-releases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i got it ;)

You create a publishing point at the server and fill up the Credentials. You go to the proxy, create a publishing point and use rtsp://server/point and fill up the same Credentials.

Each publishing point starts automatically if a client requests rtsp://proxy/point and ends after some seconds when the last unicast-player disconnects. You can use this also for multicast-streams, but you need to create a NSC-file for the player announcement. For this problem, please have a look at [Create NSC-File for multicast streaming with Windows Media Streaming](https://serverfault.com/questions/136598/create-nsc-file-for-multicast-streaming-with-windows-media-streaming)

Each proxy will split the live streams and cache the ondemand stream and considers your users credentials like authentification e.g.

Comment: Did you need to configure any of the Cache/Proxy plug-in stuff? It seems to work for me even without even enabling that plug-in, so I feel a bit weird - if the proxy plug-in is not required, then why is it there? I suspect I might be missing something...