# Create NSC-File for multicast streaming with Windows Media Streaming

Tags: windows-server-2008, streaming, multicast

For streaming multicast I need to create a NSC-file for the players - this file is pseudo-coded by Microsoft. Now I need to create this file for each proxy-publishingpoint. Is there any way to stream multicast without the NSC-file or can I create the NSC-file on another way?

Thanks for any idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

The NSC File is what tells the player the encoding format and other specifics about the stream.  This is necessary because the player is receiving a multicast stream so there is no handshake with the server or any exchange of information.  The server is just pumping out bytes to everyone and the player could tap into this stream of bytes at any point so it needs to know what it's getting to make sense of it.

[Jon Lech Johansen](http://nanocr.eu/2005/08/31/reversing-nsc/) wrote a blog post about decoding NSC files that might aid you in creating your own but unless you have a specific need, it's going to be far and away easier to just run the Multicast Announcement Wizard in the SMS interface.  If you want to do something programatically then look at Microsoft's Windows Media Services SDK, there's [an API call for announcement files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms739773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).